# Vagrant Up Authentication Failure

Tags: vagrant

I'm current doing GettingStartedWithDjango Tutorials but I've been furiously stuck/tried many solutions from other questions.

I use 'vagrant up' in the terminal and everything works ok. I can use 'vagrant halt' and do 'vagrant up' without a problem.

But once I 'vagrant ssh' and install postinstall.sh, my problem arises. I vagrant halt and and vagrant up but it comes with the following errors.

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 8000 => 8888 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

Here is the debug info:

```
INFO ssh: Attempting SSH connection...
 INFO ssh: Attempting to connect to SSH...
 INFO ssh:   - Host: 127.0.0.1
 INFO ssh:   - Port: 2222
 INFO ssh:   - Username: vagrant
 INFO ssh:   - Password? false
 INFO ssh:   - Key Path: ["/Users/kennyh/Desktop/GSWD/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key"]
 INFO ssh: SSH not ready: #<Vagrant::Errors::SSHAuthenticationFailed: SSH authentication failed! This is typically caused by the public/private
keypair for the SSH user not being properly set on the guest VM. Please
verify that the guest VM is setup with the proper public key, and that
the private key path for Vagrant is setup properly as well.>
```

Tried using PermitRootLogin without-password.. not sure if you're suppose to unhash it? (tried both anyway) still doesn't work.File was etc/sshd.config

```
# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin without-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10
```

Comment: 1. Is the Vagrant user the owner of the private key ? chown if not. 2. Set passwordless mode for ssh in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. I had faced the second one.

Comment: if passwordless mode means # Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication no.. It didn't work

Comment: Need to set 'PermitRootLogin   without-password' in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: Private key should also have 600 or 400 access mode. Otherwise SSH will complain.